# read textfile with delimiter in php

Tags: php, explode, readfile, csv

I have three eintries in a textfile.txt:

```
20100220
Hello
Here is Text \n blah \t even | and & and so on...
```

I want to read each entrie (line) as a new string in php. I thought of using fopen and fgets. But: Since I'm using special characters like \n in the last line, fgets() would not work because it will terminate the string at \n, right? In a result the last line would be just 'Here is Text '.

How can I read/explode the three lines the right way, so the \n in the last line would be interpreted as a normal string?
Thanks!

p.s.
By having three lines in my textfile.txt I indirect chose \n as a delimiter, but I could also use another delimiter. what is just the best way to read the content?

Comment: Have you tried it? As far as I know, `fgets()` looks for `"\n"` (newline), which is not the same as `'\n'` (literal string \n).

Comment: OK. No I haven't, but I'll try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1.- Use [file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) to get an array with an element for each line (separated by '\n')

```
$lines_of_file = file("myfile.txt");
//Now $lines_of_file have an array item per each line
```

2.- Use [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to get a single string you can then split by any separator you want

```
$file_content = file_get_contents("myfile.txt");
$file_content_separated_by_spaces = explode(" ", $file_content);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`file()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php), that will automatically give you an line-by-line array:

```
$rows = file('textfile.txt');
```

And even if you use fgets and such, you should be able to explode properly with `"\n"` as it is treated differently than literal `'\n'`.